# Pyqtgraph force axis labels to have decimal points

Tags: python, plot, pyqtgraph

I am trying to get my axis labels to all have decimal points, even if they happen to be integers. See the below picture.

[image]

You'll notice that on the x-axis, whenever the value is an integer, it no longer displays the decimal. I would like "1" to read "1.0".

I have a method that is setting my plot style. It reads something like this

**Plotstyle1**

```
def set_plotstyle(p1, style):
    if style == 1:
        axlabel_font = QtGui.QFont()
        axlabel_font.setPixelSize(20)

        p1.showAxis('right')
        p1.showAxis('top')

        p1.showLabel('right', show=False)
        p1.showLabel('top', show=False)

        p1.showGrid(x=False, y=False)
        p1.setLogMode(x=False, y=False)
        p1.getAxis('left').tickFont = axlabel_font
        p1.getAxis('bottom').tickFont = axlabel_font
        p1.getAxis('left').labelFont = axlabel_font
        p1.getAxis('bottom').setHeight(70)
        p1.getAxis('left').setWidth(100)
        p1.getAxis('right').setWidth(60)
        p1.getAxis('left').setStyle(tickTextOffset=15)
        p1.getAxis('bottom').setStyle(tickTextOffset=15)
        p1.getAxis('top').setStyle(showValues=False)
        p1.getAxis('right').setStyle(showValues=False)
```

If possible, I would like to set this feature within this method. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please find example code below which displays the x and y values with a single decimal place. I modified the set_plotstyle method so that it also accepts the x and y values that are being plotted. This is not exactly what you asked for, but I hope that it helps.

The x and y values are converted to formatted strings that are assigned to the tick values using setTicks. The string format command for one decimal place is .1f.  The idea and example code is based on this stackoverflow answer:

[PyQtGraph - How to set intervals of axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41078849/pyqtgraph-how-to-set-intervals-of-axis)

I reduced the font size in your set_plotstyle method so that the values do not overlap in the plot.

This is tested using Python 3.6 under Linux Mint using the Jupyter notebook. Use the %gui inline magic to display the plot if you also use Jupyter notebook.

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui

def set_plotstyle(p1, x_vals, y_vals, style):
    if style == 1:
        axlabel_font = QtGui.QFont()
        axlabel_font.setPixelSize(15)

        p1.showAxis('right')
        p1.showAxis('top')

        p1.showLabel('right', show=False)
        p1.showLabel('top', show=False)

        p1.showGrid(x=False, y=False)
        p1.setLogMode(x=False, y=False)
        p1.getAxis('left').tickFont = axlabel_font
        p1.getAxis('bottom').tickFont = axlabel_font
        p1.getAxis('left').labelFont = axlabel_font
        p1.getAxis('bottom').setHeight(70)
        p1.getAxis('left').setWidth(100)
        p1.getAxis('right').setWidth(60)
        p1.getAxis('left').setStyle(tickTextOffset=15)
        p1.getAxis('bottom').setStyle(tickTextOffset=15)
        p1.getAxis('top').setStyle(showValues=False)
        p1.getAxis('right').setStyle(showValues=False) 

        ax = p1.getAxis('bottom')
        dx = [(value, '{:.1f}'.format(value)) for value in x_vals]
        ax.setTicks([dx, []])

        ay = p1.getAxis('left') 
        dy = [(value, '{:.1f}'.format(value)) for value in y_vals]
        ay.setTicks([dy, []])
    return p1

app = pg.mkQApp()

pw = pg.PlotWidget(title="Example")
x = np.arange(7)
y = x**2/150
pw.plot(x=x, y=y, symbol='o')
pw.show()
pw.setWindowTitle('Example')
set_plotstyle(pw, x, y, 1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
    QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```