# How can I change the "resolution" of a graph in pyqtgraph?

Tags: python, plot, pyqt, pyqtgraph

I'm using pyqtgraph to plot some values ionto a timeline that goes from 0 to 20 seconds.

I get data every 100ms, and I must show it in a window of 20 seconds.
If I set my X array to be of (100*20) elements, I get a very large window in which every point in Y has its point in X.

Is there any way of having an array of 1000 elements in the x and y axis, and have my plot scale being in the range (0,20) s?

If I have my array of dimension 20, I get a "low resolution" graph, like this:
[image]

If i have an array of 1000 elements, my scale on the X axis also has 1000 elements, like this:
[image]

I need to have my data coming every 100 milliseconds, but my X scale has to be constant, of 20 seconds.

Any hint on how to achieve this?

Thank you,
David

Comment: I think this will help for you. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41078849/pyqtgraph-how-to-set-intervals-of-axis)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just giving the plot command your y data, then it will automatically assign index values to the x data.  You need to create an array of x values and pass it to the plot command as well...something like...

```
N = 100 * 20
dt = 1 / 100
x = numpy.arange(0, N) * dt
pg.plot(x, y)
```